# Extension missing for PHP, PHP 7.0.16, Mcrypt extension, AWS, on install

Tags: php, apache, php-7, mcrypt

So here is what i did:

```
sudo yum install php70-mcrypt -y
sudo service httpd restart
```

so the problem is no error were displayed during installation, but in my application i get this error

```
Mcrypt PHP extension missing!
```

and on running php in command line i get this

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so'
```

can anyone help me out with the solution I'm use amazon AWS EC2

**Edit:** 
on using sudo yum install php-mcrypt*

```
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php70-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
```

Comment: Please check my answer, it will resolve your problem. Let me know if issue still persist, i will help you further if needed.

Comment: thanks for helping me out @darshan but im still getting the error i have updated my question on it as well

Comment: Updated my answer, please check.

Comment: still getting the conflict error Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

Comment: Do you need php 7 or 5.6 will be okey? Let me know. Looks like your php versions are conflicting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167320/discussion-between-daniel-euchar-and-darshan-jain).

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 1):

*This solution will help for most of the missing PHP extension; not just mcrypt, regardless of the PHP version.*

It seems that your mcrypt extension for PHP 7 is successfully installed.

**Copy the mcrypt.so file to the PHP main module folder** so that PHP finds the mcrypt extension

.

If that does not work, or **if you need more information** to do so, try that :

1. **Search for the mcrypt so file :**

   find /usr/ -iname '*m*crypt*.so'
2. **Locate what php.ini file is using your php :**

Go on a simple page with only this code

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Then search in your browser for your php ini

3. **replace the mcrypt absolute path** in the php ini file

.

Result :
It should be working (no more Mcrypt PHP extension missing! messge), and you should be able to see information about mcrypt in the page where you had

. . . . . . . . .

Note : I cannot currently replicate those steps from the computer I am using ; so it might be that there are just tiny tweaks to do if one step is kind of not that successful

Comment: Sure i will try that and let you know

Comment: the Solution was a little different i had to copy the mcrypt.so file to the main module folder then it worked like a charm can you add this to your answer so that i can accept it

Comment: I have included your solution to the answer (see point 3 : first solution) :) I have also suggested to the community a slight change from your question's title, so that other users with other extensions issue would benefit from your post.

Comment: @DanielEuchar I have included your fix to the answer. Do you have any other questions that would prevent you to accept the answer ? How could I help ?